# Cannot create a new Rails Project with Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

I've installed Aptana Studio 3 today, and been trying to create a new Rails Project.

But nothing is being created...

I can see in the commandline it is running "rails ." instead of "rails new ." .

Any suggestion?

I'm Using:

- Windows 7
- rails 3.0.9
- ruby 1.9.2p180

Thanks,
Keren

Comment: Rails on Windows is a big headache. I finally solved it by installing Ruby 1.9.2, then Git, then Rails, and then using [Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/) as the editor. Something is up with the latest Aptana. Redcar is similar to TextMate on OSX, and seems to be working fine. You'll have to use the console for all the rails commands, but it works better that way anyway.

Comment: One thing to think about is that in Rails 2 "rails <projectname>" created a new rails app. In 3 I use "rails new <projectname>". I don't know if these two approaches to the command are separate or if both can be used in 2 and 3, but you might check and see if Aptana is confused about Rails 2 vs Rails 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

Eventually problem was that I installed ruby 1.9.2 without removing the old ruby I had on my computer (and the same was for rails).
So running ruby -v and rails -v showed the right version, but Aptana was somehow connected to the old version.

I had to uninstall both ruby and Aptana from my computer, then install the new ruby, new rails and then Aptana.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it thinks you have rails v2 installed, since it's using the old command format.  Try testing what version of ruby and rails Aptana is finding on your PATH inside it's Terminal view (Window > Show View > Terminal), by running `ruby -v` and `rails -v`.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was from the terminal within aptana IDE, created the folder for the application (as aptana does not do this since 'rails new fails') ran the command below

```
alias rails='C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails'
```

and then navigated inside the folder and typed in

```
rails new .
```

alternatively I won't have to create a folder, set the alias and type

```
rails new myapp
```

Hope this helps anybody else looking for the same information.