# Setting up Aptana Studio 3 on ubuntu using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aptana

I've set up rails using RVM in my user profile and its working perfectly fine from the terminal and using Gedit. But I wanted to use more powerful IDE which led me to Aptana Radrails. I have downloaded the latest binaries and am running it from the home/Softwares/ folder but anytime I am creating a new Rails project from the template the rails generate command does not generate anything but from command line it does. Please guide me upon how to set up Aptana Studio 3 with rails already set up using RVM. Some visual guides would really help.

OS - Ubuntu 11.04
Rails - 3.1.0
Ruby - 1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the terminal and type `rvm use 1.9.2`
then, in the same terminal, change directories to where Aptana is installed and launch Aptana using the following command `./studio3`

This will solve your problem until the next time you use Aptana. For a permanent solution, write a bash file having these commands and launch it when you wish to use Aptana.

Comment: I have already issued the `rvm use 1.9.2` command and then tried to create a new rails project in Aptana Studio 3, but no luck. Apatana is still using the old `rails [projectname]` instead of `rails new [projectname]` command to create new project.

Comment: I have set rvm default to 1.9.2 but still aptana is issuing old rails command. Also there is no choice for database I want to use in the new rails project dialog box. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 1):

May be just add your rvm rails binary's path to your /etc/environment file and export it and relogin your gnome session and try it?

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Meanwhile can you suggest anyother IDE for rails on ubuntu?

Comment: @Soham, Imm, I am only using Aptana Studio 3 nightly at both Windows and Ubuntu, so no idea about others.

Comment: Is this the permanent way to do this. I mean by setting up rails via RVM logically rails should be available anywhere from user folder right? An how did you organize your Aptana binaries? Does that make any difference?

Comment: @Soham, yes this should be permanent way to do this. and I just put aptana binaries to some folder inside my user folder, It shouldn't have any difference.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. Rails is configured fine but Aptana is issuing wrong command when creating a new rails project just as mentioned in this post - [Cannot create a new Rails Project with Aptana Studio 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941778/cannot-create-a-new-rails-project-with-aptana-studio-3)

Comment: Can anyone guide me upon what to do about the Aptana new project thing?

Comment: @Soham, few things you could try is [launching aptana from command line](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/getting_started) , and try with [aptana beta or nightly](http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/)?

Answer (score 1):

do u have any other ruby versions installed in your system.?
find it using **which ruby** before executing

Comment: I finally figured out that creating the new project from Project Explorer rather than App Explorer solves the problem. But how do I debug  from Aptana Studio 3?